# Convergence of a series in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, orthonormal

Let $\{y_k:k=1,2,\dots\}$ be an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Give and prove the necessary and sufficient conditions for the scalar sequence $\{\lambda_k\}$ such that  the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k y_k$$
converges. What is the norm of the sum of the series then?

This is my preparatory task before an exam, but I'm struggling with the first step, could you explain in detail what I'm supposed to do and what theorems to make use of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**: $\sum \lambda_k y_k$ converges $\iff$ $\sum |\lambda_k|^2$ converges.

*Sketch of proof*: since a Hilbert space is complete, the two series converge iff their partial sums are Cauchy. Since $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is orthonormal, by Pythagoras' Theorem the Cauchy conditions for the two partial sums are equivalent.

**Edit**: let 
$$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k y_k \qquad \sigma_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k|^2.$$
Then, as a conseguence of Pythagoras' theorem,
$$\begin{align}
 ||S_{n+p}-S_n||^2=&
||\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}\lambda_k y_k||^2 \\=
& \sum_{k=n}^{n+p}|\lambda_k|^2||y_k||^2 \\=
& \sum_{k=n}^{n+p}|\lambda_k|^2 \\=
&\sigma_{n+p}-\sigma_n
\end{align}
$$
From here it is clear that $(S_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is Cauchy iff $(\sigma_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is Cauchy, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd rather do it as two separate implications. First, suppose $\sum \lambda_k y_k$ converges, then $\exists N$ such that $\forall$ $n>m>N$ $||\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k y_k- \sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k y_k||^2=||\sum_{k=m+1}^n \lambda_k y_k||^2= \sum_{k=m+1}^n |\lambda_k|^2 < \epsilon$. Is it correct so far? And what conclusion do I draw now?

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, this really clears up a lot! I see that in my comment I went in the right direction but failed to observe that my last inequality is in fact the Cauchy condition for $\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $n \in \mathbb N$ we have

$||\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k y_k||^2=\sum_{k=1}^n |\lambda_k|^2 $.

Its now your turn to show:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k y_k$ converges $ \iff (\lambda_k) \in l^2$.